# Compile time errors on Mule 4 DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am new for Mulesoft Dataweave language and I am not understanding what mistake I am doing in below both code-1 and code-2 syntax. It is showing a compile time error on the if blocks. Can you please suggest what mistake am I doing in below scripts?

### Code-1

```
%dw 2.0
fun createUserData(name) = { 
    if(name=="USA"){
        readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
    }else{
        readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
    }
}
output application/json
---
createUserData("USA")
```

### code-2

```
output application/json
---
    if(payload != null){
            readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
    }else{
            readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not with the condition but the syntax for the object it returns. In DataWeave curly braces are not part of the if/else condition. The curly braces delimit an object, which contains key-value pairs. Your expression starts an object but misses the keys. Assuming the readUrl() returns an object { a: 1 } it would be equivalent to:

```
{ { a: 1} }
```

which is invalid because the outer object has no keys, only a value. In that case you could just return the result of readUrl() without the braces:

```
 if(payload != null)
            readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
    else
            readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
```

Since whatever inside each branch of the if/else are just more expressions you can transform them too.

See @Salim Khan's answer for more examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with an approach like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun createUserData(name) = { 
    a: if(name=="USA")
        readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
    else
        readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
  
}
---
createUserData("USA").a
```

Another sample script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var a  =  "1"
---
if (a == "1") ["a","b"] ++ ["c","d"] ++ [{"abc": "hello"}]
else if ( a == "2" or a == "3") {
      v: " this is ok"
}
else {
    v: "this is just ok"
}
```

Another sample:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
var a  =  "1"
var b = {"hello" : "world"}
---
if (a == "1") ["a","b"] ++ ["c","d"] ++ [{"abc": "hello"}] + (b update "hello" with "hello")
else if ( a == "2" or a == "3") {
      v: " this is ok"
}
else {
    v: "this is just ok"
}
```

Comment: hi if i want to write more logic inside if block is it possible with out curly braces?

Comment: Are you referring to something like https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_if_else ?

Comment: Will refer it but my doubt is can we implement more logic inside if block using above logic

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what do you mean by more logic? Inside of the the if condition or the section where you pass an action when a condition is met ?

Comment: Have added another sample script to see if that helps?

Comment: fun createUserData(name,payload) = { 
    a: if(name=="USA")
        readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
        payload update["wireless","required"]with(true)else (false)
    else
        readUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "application/json")
}

Comment: i want to manupulate payload as well inside if block is this possible?

Comment: I think it would be better, if you update your question with the correct input and expected output. Please do understand that DW uses functional programming constructs.

Comment: Added another script that shows how you could chain your expressions in the logic block .. Is that something that you are after?